# Magento - using custom variables to allow end user to modify styling from admin panel - Cached?

Tags: css, magento, admin

I'm planning on using Magento's inbuilt `Custom Variable` system to allow users to alter aspects of the styling. It is easy enough to bring this in to the header and have the styling options used with statements like:

```
Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('backgroundColour')->getData('store_plain_value');
```

in a custom block, and including a this in the `head` block:

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="customvars" as="customVars" template="page/html/customvars.phtml"/>
```

However, I am concerned about performance. Are the Custom Variables Cached? If I were to have, say, 40 such variables, would this be a drain on resources at all?

I know I could include them all in one as a css block, but I want to keep the additional ease-of-use gains from separating them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values from the "Custom Variables" feature in

```
System -> Custom Variables
```

are **not**, as far as I can see, cached specially.  If it helps you solve your client's problem I wouldn't let this stop you from using them.  Other things will cause performance problems sooner.

If you look at the primary place Magento uses these variables

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
public function customvarDirective($construction)
{
    $customVarValue = '';
    $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
    if (isset($params['code'])) {
        $variable = Mage::getModel('core/variable')
            ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
            ->loadByCode($params['code']);
        $mode = $this->getPlainTemplateMode()?Mage_Core_Model_Variable::TYPE_TEXT:Mage_Core_Model_Variable::TYPE_HTML;
        if ($value = $variable->getValue($mode)) {
            $customVarValue = $value;
        }
    }
    return $customVarValue;
}
```

You can see they're loaded with the following chained method call

```
$variable = Mage::getModel('core/variable')
    ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
    ->loadByCode($params['code']);
```

So you know there's no caching at this level of code.  If you jump to the `core/variable` model class file

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Variable.php
public function loadByCode($code)
{
    $this->getResource()->loadByCode($this, $code);
    return $this;
}
```

you can see theres no caching logic in the `loadByCode` method.  A quick grep through the entire file also reveals no mention of the string "cache".

Then, if you look at the model resource

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Variable.php
public function loadByCode(Mage_Core_Model_Variable $object, $code)
{
    if ($result = $this->getVariableByCode($code, true, $object->getStoreId())) {
        $object->setData($result);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

again there's no special caching logic. Also, a grep through this file for the string "cache" reveals nothing.

Finally, running the following code in an otherwise empty controller action will dump the variable values.

```
public function indexAction()
{   
    $values = Mage::getModel('core/variable')
    ->setStoreId(1)
    ->loadByCode('abc');
    var_dump($values->getData());
    exit;
}
```

If you do this, then use a separate tool to update the `core_variable_value` table and reload the page, you'll see the values are updated.

All of this points to the values not being cached.